# VS 2013 web essentials js bundle ignores output filename

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, bundle, web-essentials

It seems that all my questions are destined to have something to do with web essentials. This one is a bit weird. The bundle tag is defined like this:

```
<bundle minify="true" runOnBuild="true" output="planning-bundle.js">
```

and the file is named **planning.js.bundle**,

The thing is that on build it completely ignores the output name and creates a **planning.js** and **planning.min.js** instead of **planning-bundle.js** and **planning-bundle.min.js**. As a workaround I temporarily change the bundle name to **planning-bundle.js.bundle**.

I have vs2013 update 2, and latest webessentials. I have looked around in options for webessentials, but I cannot find where this could be controlled...I'd be grateful for any help here.

/Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the schema has changed and that output is abandoned in favor for outputDirectory. See the new format on http://vswebessentials.com/features/bundling. The other attributes are automatically converted to the new format, but output is just removed. So your workaround has become the permanent solution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. If that's the way we have to go, then that's the way.